# Ubuntu 18.04 shortcut keys not saving screenshots

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, screenshot, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME and when I press <kbd>printscreen</kbd> it saves the file to my 'Pictures' folder. But when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>printscreen</kbd> to select an area or even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> it flashes like it took the shot but isn't saving to anywhere I can find and I searched keywords to find it. Using the screenshot tool with a GUI works fine but I like using shortcuts.

Any idea why they aren't saving using those two keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a screenshot taken from the Ubuntu [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html) using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>printscreen</kbd>.

The point is, if you want the screenshot to be saved to `~/Pictures`, don't use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> captures your whole screen and **copies it to clipboard**, it doesn't save the image anywhere. You can then open an application (e.g. GIMP or LibreOffice Writer) and paste the captured screenshot.

Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> lets you capture an area and copy it to clipboard.

And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> sends screenshot of active window to the clipboard.